# linux read() function from unistd.h doesn't work for me :(

Tags: c++, linux, file-io, fcntl, unistd.h

I tried everything i could think of but for some reason it doesn't store the data from the file to "data", but the file has the written data.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char data[69]=" ";
   int fd = open("./MyFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC | O_RSYNC);
   write(fd, "HELLO", 5);
   read(fd, data, 5);

   cout << data << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Could you guys please help me. I'm trying to learn file I/O and I don't know if it's the O_RDWR or whatever that is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man write`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write):

> For a seekable file (i.e., one to which lseek(2) may be applied, for example, a regular file) writing takes place at the current file offset, and **the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes actually written.**

From [`man read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> On files that support seeking, **the read operation commences at the current file offset**, and the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes read.

You need to [seek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) back to the start of the file after your `write`, if you want to then `read` what you just wrote:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Always read and study the documentation for the functions that you use, particularly when they're not doing what you thought they would do.

Comment: oooh cool, i dint know ithe file pointer changed thank you :D

Comment: Given that you _"tried everything i could think of"_, I guess you didn't think of simply reading the documentation ;)

Comment: i will mark this as the answear in 9 mins, cant do it now :3

Comment: if anyone doesn't know what do do check out lseek()

Comment: lseek (fm, 0, SEEK_SET);

Answer (score 1):

The file descriptor position is at the end after the `write(2)`. To `read(2)` from the beginning, you need rewind the fd back to the beginning.

You can do with [`lseek`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html):

```
   write(fd, "HELLO", 5);
   lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
   read(fd, data, 5);
```

Also you should add error checks for all these system calls (open, read, write, lseek).

Comment: i did that but i removed every error check and everything to simplify the program